# Changing Console Resolution in Core (not Tiny Core) Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, console, resolution

I have recently got Core Linux, and am having trouble setting the resolution to 1920x1080 (my native resolution). I have not got a `/etc/default/grub` directory, nor have I got a UI. My question is, how can I make the console run in 1920x1080 resolution. This is what I get when I boot up:

[image]

Currently I have no extensions loaded, and it can't seem to find `xrandr`.

Comment: Your output appear to be created by the BIOS, i.e. it is not passing through the video card.  What is the output of `dmesg | grep -i vga`?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1frNMCar.jpg, by the way I'm booting it directly off of a flash drive, if that matters.

Comment: Eyup, that's using `VGA +80x25`, certainly from the BIOS.  The kernel did not even bother trying to identify the video card.  My bet is that core linux will be too small for your machine, not enough drivers to cover the hardware.

Comment: So... are you saying I can't change the resolution?

Comment: Kind of off topic, but is there anything like core that I could use with the correct resolution, going through the video card... I only want vim and GCC, why so hard :( ?

Comment: Yup, 80x25 is as far as you can get on pure BIOS.  I'd try Knoppix (very good with drivers) and/or Puppy Linux (very good on resource use)